# How to fix Openssl SMIME error :ASN1_get_object:header too long?

Tags: pdf, openssl, pkcs#7, smime

I have a .p7s file, that is a PDF signed, which is now broken and i can't open it. When trying to convert it back to PDF i am having issues.

I have tried this repair tool https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx and it was able to give me a PDF, but it looks very bad and i can't read much from it.

I have also tried this command on my Mac:

```
openssl smime -inform DER -verify -noverify -in "file.p7s" -out "file.pdf"
```

But i am receiving this error:

```
Error reading S/MIME message
140735895516104:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:152:
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to properly convert the .p7s back to a .pdf properly or fix the .p7s file so my command above works?

Comment: Can you tell the nature of the damage to your p7s container and its pdf contents? Or simply share the pdf in question?

Comment: I don't really know the nature of the damage, and i can't share the file, as it is very senzitive information.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes attempts to help you pure guesswork.